# Check permissions for user

Tags: php

I am trying to make permission page thy will check if user have full access than some option allow to this person.I have table named users there i have 5 columns name `user_id` , `username` , `password` , `email` , `permission`
respectively .so now i am showing what i have done.

**permissions.php**

```
<?php
  include('db.php');
     $result=mysql_query("SELECT permission,user_id  FROM users");


        while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
        $test['user_id'];
        $test['permission'];

        }


  ?>
```

For example mysql result on first row: `$test['user_id'] = 1`  and `$test['permission'] = full` .

Session result: `$_SESSION['user_name'] = admin`

So how can i check if this user id have permission full than do some think.

I am new on php sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT permission,user_id  FROM users WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user_name]'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        $data = mysql_fetch_row($result); // fetch first row of result, we don't need a loop, as username should be unique
        $permission = $data['permision'];
        $user_id = $data['user_id'];
    }else{
        echo "Username not found.";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if user have full permission, store in session full permission

```
 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {                    
    $_SESSION['permission'] = $test['permission'];
  }
```

check if user have full permission

```
   if($_SESSION['permission'] == full){
    //do shomething
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  include('db.php'); // though you should look in to "PDO"

  // default permission--disallowed
  $allowed = false;

  // get the permission for the current user (based on the username within
  // your session variable). also make sure to sanitize anything that's being
  // placed within a query to the database.
  $query = sprintf("SELECT permission "
                  ."FROM users "
                  ."WHERE username = '%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_name']));
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while (($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false){
    // we found the username, now check their access
    $allowed = $test['permission'] == 'full';
  }

  // if ($allowed){
  //   super secret area
  // } else {
  //   get out of here
  // }
```